# Can't update cocoa pods Error: Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when trying to update my cocoa pods...
[image: My error]

Any help would be great. Thanks internet.

Comment: I am currently facing this issue while `pod install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. Here's the reason:

http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/03/30/github-may-have-been-targeted-by-chinese-hackers-in-ddos-attack/

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. I figured it out not too long after I posted this. lol